# matplotlib polar scatter plot: How do I change the units to anything but degrees?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the matplotlib polar scatter plot, how can I change the units of the *theta* axis from angle to arbitrarily-specified units?

Starting from https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html (where all the examples are in degrees),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# Compute areas and colors
N = 150
r = 2 * np.random.rand(N)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
area = 200 * r**2
colors = theta

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

*The theta axis is always in degrees*. What if I want it in, say, days, for a given function `degrees=days2degrees(days)`? Should I make use of

```
ax.set_thetalim()
ax.set_thetamin()
ax.set_thetamax()
```

etc.? These seem to require inputs in *degrees*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this answers your question:

Just add something like

```
t = ax.get_xticks()
# your function
days = t/(2 * np.pi)  * 365
ax.set_xticklabels(days, fontsize=12)
```

Comment: then I did not understand the question